# Как можно узнать отображемый цвет в Safari и Safari Mobile (iOS)?

Tags: html, css, safari, color, apple

Приходят видео с непрозрачным фоном для установки в качестве фона на сайте от дизайнеров. Сталкиваюсь с проблемой сходства цветов фона, установленного мной для body, и фона на видео, иногда методом тыка получалось подобрать цвет для body, который бы совпадал с цветом видео. BrowserStack не дает возможности использовать пипетку в сафари, хочу узнать, если ли другой способ для устранения проблемы?

Comment: ты не подберешь цвет для видео, в разных браузерах будет по-разному. Лучше или гифки использовать, или секвенции из картинок.

Comment: @VladykoD видимо всё завязано на передаче метаданных о цветовом пространстве, поэтому в разных браузерах по разному обрабатывается цвет, а если картинки для каждого кадра большие, как поступить?

Comment: я на одном своем проекте получила вместо видео пачку картинок и склеивала их в видео с помощью этой утилиты, она сделает прозрачный фон, но копаться в ней больно: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9

Comment: @VladykoD спасибо, попробую поработать с ffmpeg, обычно когда получаешь пачку картинок, то думаешь в сторону canvas

Comment: не, канвас в этой ситуации не поможет :) Если только не рисовать анимацию с нуля

Comment: @VladykoD а если использовать requestAnimationFrame с одним большим спрайтом?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135312/discussion-between-vladykod-and-highpassion).

Answer (score 0):

Пипетка, которая встроена в macOS(Digital Color Master), работает в открытых приложениях

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: а еще требует покупки Mac, вы предлагаете мне покупать устройство для тестов? Поднять виртуалку бессмысленно также.

Comment: кстати, для тестов можно взять https://www.browserstack.com/ , там с бесплатного акка или минута, или 5 доступны. В общем, можно проверить, но очень-очень быстро.

Comment: @VladykoD на что я и трачу много времени, однако ты не можешь использовать пипетку на браузерстаке, как я написал в вопросе

Comment: сорян, упустила